# how can i pass int as argument for where clause in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am taking int values with intent.getExtra()... and i want to use it in where clause. so how to do it as it takes only string as argument.

```
String keyvalue;    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile);
        keyvalue = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key")

 public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getAllMobiles() {
        ArrayList <HashMap<String,String>> wordlist;
        wordlist= new ArrayList <HashMap<String, String>>();
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE _id =?";  

        SQLiteDatabase database = sql.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(Query, new String[] {keyvalue});
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(Sqlite.SUBCATEGORY_NAME, cursor.getString(2));          
            wordlist.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the int to a string, use e.g.

```
String.valueOf(keyvalue)
```

so the query becomes

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { String.valueOf(keyvalue) });
```

Comment: thanks... Can you tell me.. what does it mean?? static field Sqlite.subcategory_id should be accesd in static way.. As when i am using this code h.putExtra("key", sql.SUBCATEGORY_ID); and above code, i am getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse your integer value into string and add it to your sql Query